# Как понять, где писать тело функций, и где их декларировать? (Windows Forms Application Visual C++ VC2013)

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня есть Visual C++ проект, Windows Forms Application (Win32) в Visual Studio 2013. В данном проекте есть два файла: *MyForm.h* и *MyForm.cpp*.

Моя цель - запрограммировать генетический алгоритм, который будет решать задачу. Входные параметры к этой задаче, а так же промежуточные и финальные результаты должны появляться на экране, в соответствующих контролах.

Я создала дизайн формы. У меня есть доступ к обработчикам событий,
но не могу понять:

- Где писать сам код моих функций?
- Как их сделать доступными для обработчиков событий на форме?

К примеру, на форме есть кнопка: LoadKnapsack.
В `.h` файле я могу прописать код в событии:

```
private: System::Void LoadKnapsack_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
}
```

На этом событии я хочу вызвать функцию, которая будет считывать данные из файла и записывать их в массив. После этого, уже непосредственно в обработчике, этот массив будет обходиться (возможно другой функцией) и результаты будут записываться в соответствующие контролы на форме.
Вопросы:

1. Где необходимо хранить тело такой функции? (в `.cpp` файле или в `.h`
   файле?);
2. Где необходимо прописать прототип такой функции? в этом же файле MyForm.h?

Или мне надо создать новый .h файл со всеми прототипами функций, которые будут работать непосредственно в моём генетическом алгоритме, и к нему соответственно .cpp файл, в котором будут жить тела этих функций), а оба файла прописать директивой #include в .h  файле формы?

Логика подсказывает, что `MyForm.h`, в которой описывается класс моей формы, а так же происходят обработчики событий - всё же не то место, где следовало бы хранить код функций, которые я буду вызывать в обработчиках.

Comment: Вам бы для начала изучить основы, прежде чем браться за реализацию генетического алгоритма.

Comment: :) спасибо, это очень ценное замечание, но деваться некуда.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему вы выбрали C++/CLI. Если вам нужен UI, почему не C#, он существенно проще. (C++ и C++/CLI — это разные вещи.)

Comment: с c++ знакома, по крайней мере. с# - не изучала на должном уровне что бы пытаться с ходу запрограммировать генетический алгоритм :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код можно писать где угодно, единственное что если тело функции находится в .h файле, то функция должна быть помечена как inline.

Желательно не мешать основной код программы с кодом UI. По этому лучше вынести код в новый файл whatsitsname.h и включить его в MyForm.h.
Совсем не обязательно выносить тела функций в отдельный .cpp файл, весь код можно писать в .h файлах. (Вынос тел функций в .cpp файлы имеет смысл только в больших проектах)

Также желательно написать юнит-тесты, чтобы не тестировать всё руками.

Comment: большое спасибо, я разобралась.